# Scale a pyplot plot while keeping the x to y ratio intact

Tags: matplotlib

I currently have this plot

[image]

However at some coordinates, such as (1,1) or (2,2) the data is quite crowded and hard to read. I would like to scale up the y and x axis by the same amount. I have tried figsize but the x to y ratio of the plot is not conserved, and the legend is also displaced, as shown here :

[image]

Is there a way to scale the plot up? Ideally, I want something like adjusting figsize, but the height is worked out from the input width.

Comment: Without a full minimal reproducible example it is heard to guess how the plot is created.   Did you use an approach such as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4701285/12046409) to position the legend?  Note that in a logscale plot, you can't have a fixed x/y ratio, but you can scale the figsize in some proportional amount.

Comment: `ax.set_aspect()` can be used to control the h/w aspect. This can be played around with in addition to the `figsize` to get the desired output. Also, using `ax.legend` should not result in a displaced legend, but `fig.legend` can. But as @JohanC says, without a minimal example, it is difficult to tell what is required here